# Is there progress_transform which shows the progress bar like progress_apply?

Tags: python, pandas, tqdm

I am trying to use df["series"].transform instead of df["series"].apply. For .apply we have .progress_apply after initiate

```
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas
df["series"].progress_apply(function)
```

however, I cant find the version for .progress_transform. I know we can use other tqdm methods like loop it but I just wish to know whether do we have .progress_transform? thank you

Comment: Short answer: no, but there is virtually no difference between Series.apply and Series.transform in general, so just use `progress_apply`, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe we can look at the actual source code and change apply to transform?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

def tqdm_pandas(t):
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
    def inner(df, func, *args, **kwargs):
        t.total = groups.size // len(groups)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            t.update(1)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        result = df.transform(wrapper, *args, **kwargs)
        t.close()
        return result
    DataFrame.progress_transform = inner
    
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (100000, 6)))

# Register `pandas.progress_apply` and `pandas.Series.map_apply` with `tqdm`
# (can use `tqdm.gui.tqdm`, `tqdm.notebook.tqdm`, optional kwargs, etc.)
tqdm.pandas(desc="my bar!")


df.groupby(0)[5].progress_transform(sum)
```